# How to understand the following thing physically in Hilbert spaces?

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, convex-cone

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space. Normal cone is defined like this: For a convex set $C$, the associated normal cone $$N_C(x) = \{z \in X: \langle z, y-x\rangle \leq 0 \quad   \ \forall \ \ y \in C\}$$ of $C$ at point $x \in C$.

Can someone tell me what is its physical interpretation. Why it is normal?

Comment: Try taking $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ and drawing a picture.

Comment: Note that 'normal' is to be understood in the sense of 'orthogonal' or 'perpendicular'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often called the [*dual cone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_cone_and_polar_cone). Wikipedia has this illustration (here $x=0$ and $C$ is neither convex nor contains $x$, but the concept is the same):

[image: dual cone]

Think of the dual cone $C^*$ as the set of directions such that starting from $x$, you don't move away from any point of $C$ (initially). When $C$ is itself a cone, $C^*$ consists of the linear functionals that are bounded below on $C$. This suggests that the concept may be relevant in linear programming and it is, as the article [Conic optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_optimization) indicates.

Dual/normal cone is the same thing in the world of convex cones as [polar set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_set) is in the world of convex sets.